# github permission denied after user switch

Tags: git, github, permission-denied

Facing a wired issue when I do git push.
I used to use one old github account in my mac, assume the account user name is ***peterOld***. Right now I change to use a new github account, just call it ***peterNew***. I changed ssh key on server side, and changed 'git config' in my mac to make sure use peterNew. I clone one repo from peterNew's server and did a commit using peterNew. However, when I run 'git push', I got permission denied. 
remote: Permission to peterNew/repo-name.git denied to peterOld.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/peterNew/repo-name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
I was wondering why the push shows peterOld? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Peter,
did you add the keys here:
https://github.com/settings/keys
?

Comment: Thanks Ochkarik, I added ssh keys here.